# Refactoring large method to create custom UIView in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to refactor a method correctly in my `UIViewController`. I am fairly new to Objective-C so trying to understand what would be the best approach here. The method is to create a custom bottom bar on the screen. It is a `UIView` and has multiple subviews and auto layout.

At present the whole creation of the bar is in one method and around 300 lines. Ideally I want to move this into a subclass but need to understand how to complete this correctly.

Here is the start of the method to get a feel for what it does:

```
-(void)setupBottomBarViewForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)forOrientation {
UIView *bottomBarInnerView = [UIView autolayoutView];
[self.bottomBarView addSubview:bottomBarInnerView];

NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(bottomBarInnerView);
NSDictionary *bottomBarMetrics = @{@"minVPadding":@2.0};
[self.bottomBarView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(minVPadding)-[bottomBarInnerView]-(minVPadding)-|" options:0 metrics:bottomBarMetrics views:views]];
[self.bottomBarView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:bottomBarInnerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.bottomBarView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:1]];

NSString *word = @"Word";
NSUInteger letterCount = [word length];

NSMutableArray *viewList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // Create an array to store the tiles within
NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"letterTileMinHeight":@40.0,@"padding":@3.0,@"letterViewPadding":@5.0}; // Constraint metrics
... [OTHER LOGIC] which create multiple subviews further UIViews and UILabels ...
```

Is the best route to move this into a `UIView` subclass? Then where does the customisation code go into (which method)? Also how is it then called from the VC and have the auto layout creation?

I understand subclassing etc, the main question is behind how the auto layout constraints are created. Some of the later auto layout constraints link to self.view from the `UIViewController` so should this view then be passed into the new method which creates the banner bar subview??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should absolutely make it a UIView subclass.  Pass whatever you need to configure it.  Looks like a dictionary right now, so you could call your init method something like

```
-(MyNewView*)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict  {}
```

The view subclass will set up its own constraints for the things that are inside it.  If the view controller that's using it needs contraints over the whole subview then it should add them, but it shouldn't mess with the ones inside it.

Here's an example of a subview init method that takes string & count, creates two labels to show them, and adds them to itself.  You could layoutSubviews or autolayout to position them within the new view.

```
-(BottomBarInnerView *)initWithString:(NSString *)string count:(NSNumber*)count {
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
    label.text = string;
    [self addSubview:label];

    UILabel *countLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 20, 10)];
    countLabel.text = [count stringValue];
    [self addSubview:countLabel];

    return self;
}
```

Since the view uses CGRectZero you'll need to resize it when you create it, so it would be something like:

```
BottomBarInnerView* bottomBarInnerView = [[BottomBarInnerView alloc] initWithString:@"Hi Mom" count:@(42)];
bottomBarInnerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 100, 50);
[self.view addSubview:bottomBarInnerView];
```

Alternatively you could add constraints to it, and let autolayout set the frame for you.

Comment: Ok, do I create a subview of `UIView` then within the init method call the initWithDictionary or whatever I end up using? I have seen it done with layoutSubViews etc, what method/approach should I use in the actual subview class?

Comment: in your initWithDictionary you'll do self = [super init], which makes your object into a UIView. After that, do whatever you need to do to make it yours. Add subviews, sure, then lay them out in layoutSubviews, or use autolayout, which it seems like you wanted to do originally.

Comment: Hey @jsd. The actual requirement here would be to make the `bottomBarInnerView` from the question. The dictionary would not be needed as that is used for the constraints on that view. I need to subclass `UIView` to make the `bottomBarInnerView`. So the string, count etc would be passed into the relevant new init method and the code [AFTER] the big block above. Anyhow, the question is how do I subclass the `UIView` and correctly configure that. I.e. do I subclass `UIView` and then call alloc/init - then put all the code after. Or do I create a custom `initWithString` method then call...

Comment: ...alloc/initWithString ? Then in that method in the subclass it calls `super self`? Sorry it the whole call to the subclass and custom init method in subclass thats causing the confusion. Thanks

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a code example, as it's too long for this comment.